# sinon trying to spy express res object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, sinon

I'm trying to test this simple express middleware function

```
function onlyInternal (req, res, next) {
  if (!ReqHelpers.isInternal(req)) {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send() <-- TRYING TO ASSERT THIS LINE
  }
  next()
}
```

This is my test currently

```
describe.only('failure', () => {
      let resSpy
      before(() => {
        let res = {
          status: () => {
            return {
              send: () => {}
            }
          }
        }

        resSpy = sinon.spy(res, 'status')
      })

      after(() => {
        sinon.restore()
      })

      it('should call next', () => {
        const result = middleware.onlyInternal(req, resSpy)
        expect(resSpy.called).to.be.true
      })
    })
```

And i'm getting this error: `TypeError: res.status is not a function`

Why is res.status not a function? It clearly looks like a function to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sinon.spy` returns newly created spy, not `res` that has new spy applied.

So in your case: `resSpy === res.status` and not as you would expected `resSpy === res`, that wouldn't make sense.

In other words, you should still pass original `res` to you middleware:

```
const result = middleware.onlyInternal(req, res);
```

Comment: At first your suggestion seems opposite of what worked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407877/sinon-spy-on-function-not-working/51409612#51409612 but I think I see that the difference between these 2 scenario's is that when spying on a single function, I need to pass that new spy in, but when i'm spying on an object.function, I need to pass in the original object

Comment: Yes, spy is just an building block. Remember your tested code uses `res`, so you must pass whole `res` regardless of what spies it has installed in properties.